# Simple gesture recognizers

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to trigger one gesture during the execution of another gesture?  Let's say I have gesture A which is a pan gesture and B is a long press gesture. Can B fire up during the pan with the finger remaining on the screen ?      Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely!  Apple even provides you delegate methods to control this behavior, most notably:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizershouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```